# How to prove that $W_1\cap W_2\supset$ Span$(S_1\cap S_2)$ if $W_1=$ Span$(S_1)$ and $W_2=$ Span$(S_2)$ are subspaces of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In my opinion, let $v\in$ Span($S_1\cap S_2$) and therefore $v\in$ Span$(S_1)$ and $v\in$ Span$(S_2)$. Write $v=c_1z_1+...+ c_nz_n$ where $z_k\in S_1\cap S_2$ and $c_k\in R$. Here I am feeling I have the wrong direction. Could someone suggest how to approach the question?

And how do you show that $W_1\cap W_2\ne$ Span$(S_1\cap S_2)$ in general?

Comment: Your proof is ok. However, if you choose $S_1=S_2$, then $W_1=W_2$ and there is no strict inequality between sets in your question.

Comment: Are these linear algebra spans, or ring-theoretic spans?

Answer (score 2):

Span$(S_1\cap S_2)\subset $ Span$(S_1)=W_1$ and Span$(W_1\cap W_2)\subset $ Span$(S_2)=W_2$.

In the 1-dimensional space $R$, the real numbers we have $R=$Span$(\{1\}=$Span$(\{2\}$
but
Span$(\{1\})\cap \{2\})=$Span$(\emptyset)=\{0\}.$

Answer (score 0):

$W_1=W_2$ and there is no strict inequality between sets in your question. In general anything can happen. Even when $W_1=W_2$ you can have $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$. If $S_1\subseteq S_2$, then again you have an equality, since in this case $W_1\cap W_2=W_1$ and $\mathrm{Span}(S_1\cap S_2)=\mathrm{Span(S_1)}=W_1.$ In general, you need to consider your given example and check what are $W_1$, $W_2$ and what is their intersection. The same goes for the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. Just note that the intersection of sets can be very small, even empty, the intersection of subspaces can be big - even the whole space.