# Is the following true: $v \in Span(S_1 \cap S_2)$ $\implies$ $v \in Span(S_1)$ and $v \in Span(S_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble getting an intuitive sense of 'span'.

I've been trying to work out a proof for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646688/how-to-prove-that-w-1-cap-w-2-supset-spans-1-cap-s-2-if-w-1-spans-1?rq=1), and like the poster there my proof hinges on the subject of this question being true, but I get the sense it may be incorrect to make that assumption.

I'd appreciate if someone could offer a proof, counter-example, or some insight.

FWIW: this is not an assignment question, I'm just studying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The span of $S$ is composed of all the vectors you can get by adding vectors in $S$ and multiplying by elements of your field $k$ (maybe $\mathbb{R}$ in your case). The basic fact to get about this, in relation to your question is :

If $S \subset S'$, then $Span(S) \subset Span(S')$. Now this is intuitive : if you can make a linear combination with vectors in $S$ then you can make it with the same vectors which are in $S'$.

Now you can just apply this to your question, with $S = S_1 \cap S_2$, and $S' = S_1$ then $S' = S_2$.